# Wicket replacement "only on component added to parent"

Tags: java, wicket

I get an exception from Wicket 1.4.11 reading:

> 2010-11-03 17:44:51,971 [http-8080-1] ERROR org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle - Method onFormSubmitted of interface org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.IFormSubmitListener targeted at component [MarkupContainer [Component id = customer]] threw an exception
>   org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Method onFormSubmitted of interface
>   org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.IFormSubmitListener targeted at component [MarkupContainer [Component id = customer]] threw an exception
>        at  org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.invoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:193)
>       ...
>       Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       ...
>       Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This method can only be called on a component that has already been added to its parent.
>        at org.apache.wicket.Component.replaceWith(Component.java:2804)
>        at no.magge.iumb.web.crm.customers.PrivateCustomerTab$1.onSubmit(PrivateCustomerTab.java:34)
>        at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.delegateSubmit(Form.java:1565)

This happened when I clicked the `cancel_btn` of a form in a panel in a tabbedpanel in a tabbedpanel... Here is the code for `cancel_btn`:

```
public class PrivateCustomerTab extends Panel {

 private static final long serialVersionUID = 16L;

 protected Panel getCurrentPanel() {
  return this;
 }

 public PrivateCustomerTab(String id, long customerId, final Panel backPanel) {
  super(id);

  final PrivateCustomerForm form = new PrivateCustomerForm("customer", customerId) {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 4L;
   @Override
   protected void onSubmit() {
    System.out.println("\n\n(formsubmit) HELLO THERE MY PARENT IS: " + getParent() + "\n\n");
    if (customerId!=0) {
     PrivateCustomerTab.this.replaceWith(new PrivateCustomerTab("panel", customerId, backPanel));
    }
   }
  };
  add(form);

  Button cancelButton = new Button("cancel_btn", new ResourceModel("cancel")) {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 18L;
   @Override
   public void onSubmit() {
    System.out.println("\n\n(cancelsubmit) HELLO THERE MY PARENT IS: " + getParent() + "\n\n");
    if (backPanel!=null) {
     // PrivateCustomerTab.this.replace(backPanel);
     getCurrentPanel().replaceWith(new CustomerListTab("panel"));

    }
   }
  };
  cancelButton.setVisible(backPanel!=null);
  form.add(cancelButton);
        }
}
```

I've been trying various way to get the current panel, the one I want to replace. One way is using the `getCurrentPanel()` method which just returns `this` from the panel class. Another way is doing `PrivateCustomerTab.this.replaceWith(...)`, and I've also tried `getParent().getParent().replaceWith(...)`. These all give me the message that I cannot replace something that isn't added to its parent.

I think I must be misunderstanding some key concept here. Maybe forms are processed before my panel is added to its parent, meaning I cannot replace the panel in `cancel_btn`'s `onSubmit()`?

I've tried Googling my way and looking for something about it in my copy of *Wicket in Action*. Please help me understand... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is not really about finding the right panel.
That seems to be ok.
All three calls do seem to find the same panel.

It is about, were the panel itself is added to. To replace itself with something els a component needs to ask the parent, were it is added to.
Then it ask its parent to forget about itself and choose the given Component as a child.

So wicket basically complains that the panel is not added to any component.

Was the component hierachy changed in the mean time?

Comment: No, the hierarchy should not have changed as far as I understand. I have a link which does replaceWith() and replaces in this PrivateCustomerTab panel. I don't change the markup or do anything to manipulate the hierarchy between that and the cancel_btn's onSubmit-method.

Comment: I see your point about the issue being that my Panel now, somehow, has no parent. So thank you for that...

Comment: Marked this as useful. Found the problem and posted answer below. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this one out - newbie mistake (again), I guess.

What happens is that the forms `onSubmit()` is called before the `cancel_btn`'s `onSubmit()`. Since the first these methods replaces the panel, naturally the second time one tries to replace that same panel it's not added to a parent any more.

To solve it I moved my forms `onSubmit()` code into the my save buttons `onSubmit()`. By doing this there is only 1 `onSubmit()` method called, depending on what button was clicked.

Comment: Really? How odd: "Wicket first calls the button's `onSubmit` method and then (if not configured otherwise) calls the form's `onSubmit` method." - _Wicket in Action_, p157

Comment: Odd. I'll give it another debug run.